# How to give validation to collapsible content block using jquery validation Enginejs

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova-2.0.0, jquery-validation-engine

I have created and collapsible content which has some fields and for validation I have used **jquery.validationEngine.js**.The problem is when collapsible is true it doesn't show validation option but if its false it works fine what I want is if there is an error in the collapsible content it should set collapsible to false.

Here is the code for html page :

```html
<div data-role="collapsible" id='collapsible_2' data-theme="b" data-content-theme="c" style="padding-bottom: 10px">
  <h3>Contact Information</h3>
  <p align="left" style="margin-bottom: 2px"><font color="#3C6FA1"><b>EMAIL ADDRESS</b></font></p>
   <hr>
  <input class="validate[required] text-input" id="email_id" name="emailId" type="text" placeholder="name@sample.com" >
  <p align="left" style="margin-bottom: 2px"><font color="#3C6FA1"><b>PHONE NUMBER</b></font></p>
   <hr>
  <input class="validate[required] text-input" id="main" name="main" type="number" min="0" max="9" maxlength="10" placeholder="Main" >
  <input class="validate[required] text-input" id="mobile" name="mobile" type="text" placeholder="Mobile" >
  <p align="left" style="margin-bottom: 2px"><font color="#3C6FA1"><b>FAX NUMBER</b></font></p>
   <hr>
  <input class="validate[required] text-input"id="fax" name="fax" type="text" placeholder="Fax" >
  <p align="left" style="margin-bottom: 2px"><font color="#3C6FA1"><b>WEBSITE</b></font></p>
   <hr>
  <input class="validate[required] text-input" id="website" name="website" type="text" placeholder="Website" >
  <p align="left" style="margin-bottom: 2px"><font color="#3C6FA1"><b>ADDRESS</b></font></p>
   <hr>
  <input class="validate[required] text-input" id="street_address" name="street_address" type="text" placeholder="Street Address">
  <input class="validate[required] text-input" id="city" name="city" type="text" placeholder="City">
  <input class="validate[required] text-input" id="Region" name="Region" type="text" placeholder="Region">
  <input class="validate[required] text-input" id="postal_code" name="postal_code" type="text" placeholder="Postal Code">
  <select name="select-choice-c" id="select-choice-c" data-native-menu="false" data-theme="a">
    <option>Select Country</option>
    <option value="standard">India</option>
    <option value="rush">Australia</option>
    <option value="express">England</option>
    <option value="overnight">SriLanka</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

here is the java script I had used:

```js
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
 // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
 jQuery("#formID").validationEngine();
});
```

here is the js and css files i had used for design and validation:

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/template.css" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="contactcss/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css"/>
  <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: You mean collapse/expand?

Comment: yup I solved the problem just make changes in js file and it worked.But know what i want is when validation fails it should set callapse to false means it should point to that field.

Answer (score 0):

just made some changes in the jquery.validationEngine.js files as shown below
from:

```
if (!options.validateNonVisibleFields && (field.is(":hidden") && !options.prettySelect || field.parent().is(":hidden")))
            return false;
```

To:

```
if (!options.validateNonVisibleFields && (field.is(":hidden") && !options.prettySelect || field.parent().is(":hidden")))
            return true;
```

and
from :

```
validateNonVisibleFields: false,  lineNo:2008
```

To:

```
validateNonVisibleFields: true,
```