# How to expand collapse dynamicall using jquery mobile in phonegap android when validation fails

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova-2.0.0, jquery-validation-engine

I have created an page in which i am using jquery.validationEngine.js. Is setting an error popup even when the collapse is in true state but what i want is I am using 2 collapse in the app so when i open one another will be in close.and if i forget to add or miss a field in one collapse and open another it will popup error but it does not focus at the field sense collapse is in true state.So what i want is is the collapse is in true state and validation fails in that collapse it should expand that collapse.Can anyone tell me how to do this.
Here is the link for the collapse that i have create with js and css files i have used:

[How to give validation to collapsible content block using jquery validation Enginejs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17697172/2307391)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `.trigger('expand')` and `trigger('collapse')`. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/vCR2H/

Comment: hey thanks but i want when i receive status false from the validationEngine it should expand the collapsible on its on not by clicking on the button

Comment: I never worked on jq validation, but if you could set a jsfiddle, I can check it.